# jquery: if other slidetoggle is enabled (visible), close before initiating new slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following script.  I've got 3 div's that are all display: hidden; that I want to drop down from the top of the page using slideToggle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#irN").click(function () {
   $('#irN_dd').slideToggle();
});

$("#myir").click(function () {
   $('#myir_dd').slideToggle();
});

$("#myirmsg").click(function () {
   $('#myirmsg_dd').slideToggle();
});

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a id="irN">irN</a>
<a id="myir">myir</a>
<a id="myirmsg">myirmsg</a>
```

This script works great.  The only issue is that all 3 can be opened at the same time.  I only want 1 to be able to be open at any given time.  So...how would I modify the script to do the following..

... if none are open and the viewer clicks one of the id's, it opens....
... if one of the divs are open and the viewer clicks another one of the id's, it slides the one open up and then slides the new one down.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit in regard to comments*

If you didn't want to check the markup etc, you could use something like the following to acheive what you wanted:

```
$("#irN, #myir, #myirmsg").click(function () {      
  var example = "#" + this.id + "_dd";
  $(example).siblings("div[id$=_dd]").slideUp()
                                     .is(":visible") 
                                     ?  $(example).delay(1000).slideToggle() 
                                     :  $(example).slideToggle(); 
});
```

This fits all your functions into one concise event (could probably look nicer but I'm too tired to think of anything better right now).

<kbd>[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4nvU/10/)</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to make it delay between going up and coming down?  Right now it looks kinda bad the way I have it designed.  I only want there to be a delay if it is closing one to open another.  Right now the close and open is happening at the same time

Comment: that puts a delay no matter what. I only want the delay if it has to slide up one to slide down the other.  If none are open, I don't want delay.

Comment: this leaves both of them open for a short period of time.  I don't want the new onbe to open til the old one is closed.  Sorry to be so hard.

Comment: @KDJ Here - http://jsfiddle.net/a4nvU/9/. It's not pretty, but I'll try and shorten it a bit.

Comment: I saw your shorter version.  What does `$(example).siblings("div[id$=_dd]")` mean?  I like the code.  I'm giving you the answer.  Sorry, fell asleep last night.  But, if you can, can you still explain that to me?

Comment: @KDJ It means the elements <div> siblings whose ID's end in _dd, and no worries!